SwiperJs hide slides when i change direction of document
Here I fetch some todos and display them in swiper.
If after I swipe then change direction the slides will disappear.
see problem in sandbox 
export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [direaction, setDireaction] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setTodos(data));
  }, []);
  const handleDir = () => {
    document.documentElement.dir = direaction ? "rtl" : "ltr";
    setDireaction(!direaction);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Swiper slidesPerView={5}>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <SwiperSlide>{todo.title}</SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
      <button onClick={handleDir}>change direction</button>
    </div>
  );
}

